# Javascript setInterval function, escaping on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const getDataFromServer = async () => {
    var response = setInterval(()=> {
        var w = axios.get('/yet')
        if(w.data === 'done') {
            nextStep();
            clearInterval(response)
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

`What this code does is that It keeps asking the server if the processing(In my case it's text to image generation using python,flask) is done yet.(every secend) And as soon as it gets 'done' response It should stop asking immediately and move on to the next step(it's form-wizard-style react app). I checked the browser's network tab in the developer tool and the response was correct(changed to 'done' after the process has been done) but it doesn't move to the next step and doesn't stop asking.

`I just need this axios.get to stop as soon as it gets 'done' response.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure the `axios.get` returns a promise, so the `w` variable is actually a promise object and not the response. You can try something like this instead.

```
const getDataFromServer = () => {
   const interval = setInterval(async () => {
        const w = await axios.get('/yet');

        if (w.data === 'done') {
            nextStep();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

See also the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) about promises.

Comment: I would chain setTimeouts instead of using setInterval at all. He wants a fixed period between the end of the function to the next start of the call